# Issue using Kafka with Spark using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to consume data using Spark published by kafka, but I am unable to do so. I am using Spark 2.2.

1. I want to consume data sent by Kafka using Spark, process it and store in local file or HDFS.
2. I want to print out the data sent out by kafka (consumed by spark) in console after running spark job.

For Kafka, I am following this tutorial: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

```
    [cloudera@quickstart kafka]$ ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
    >message 1
    >message 2 
    >message 3
    >message 4
```

Run Spark python script file.py:

```
./spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0 file.py
```

Pyspark code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("stream").getOrCreate()

df = spark\
.readStream\
.format("kafka")\
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")\
.option("subscribe","test")\
.load()

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "topic")


#Trying to save result in a file
df.writeStream\
.format("text")\
.option("checkpointLocation", "file:///home/cloudera/file.txt")\
.option("path","file:///home/cloudera/file.txt")\
.start()
# Does not write to a file

#Trying to print result in console
df.writeStream()\
.outputMode("append")\
.format("console")\
.start()
# Does not print to console and gives error: TypeError: 'DataStreamWriter' object is not callable
```

Any help?

Comment: just to make sure, you started spark **THEN** produced data right?

Comment: @Falan yes I started kafka first. I want to know how to store data into HDFS from spark streaming.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could well be this line:

```
df.writeStream()\
```

remove the `()` from the line like so:

```
df.writeStream\
```

Comment: Hello @antoine, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a minute to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Answers are more helpful when they explain what OP has done wrong and why. Please edit your answer to describe why your code will work instead of OP's.